# Invalid layout of the ARFF file

Tags: python, arff

I have an ARFF file generated from liac-weka package.

```
 % Finger-tapped_dataset
    @RELATION Feature_onsets
    @ATTRIBUTE file STRING
    @ATTRIBUTE nOnset INTEGER
    @ATTRIBUTE Duration REAL
    @ATTRIBUTE RMS.mean REAL
    @ATTRIBUTE RMS.var REAL
    @ATTRIBUTE spectralCentroid.mean REAL
    @ATTRIBUTE spectralCentroid.var REAL

    @DATA
    sound_1,1,0.859138309956,0.00811793841422,0.000330115522956,0.0686389952898,8.52151861181e-05
    sound_1,2,0.719818592072,0.0209680441767,0.00351395853795,0.0674178153276,0.000161568881595
    sound_1,3,0.661768734455,0.021980991587,0.00362967769615,0.0664032921195,0.000200695401873
    sound_1,4,0.441179126501,0.0213470663875,0.0032624185551,0.0699469298124,0.00039628680679
    sound_1,5,0.9287981987,0.0224026963115,0.00370181445032,0.0690619647503,0.000339957477991
    sound_1,6,0.917188227177,0.0215289667249,0.00351273571141,0.0691223442554,0.000326170702465
    sound_1,7,0.441179126501,0.0240413267165,0.00402954593301,0.0688840150833,0.000323307351209
    sound_1,8,0.243809521198,0.0253500081599,0.00412592897192,0.0682555362582,0.000328328402247
    sound_1,9,0.673378705978,0.0244132820517,0.00386085407808,0.0677450224757,0.000302833941532
    sound_1,10,0.487619042397,0.025617858395,0.004043656867,0.06802662462,0.000307480600895
    sound_1,11,1.61451244354,0.0236539077014,0.00386097631417,0.0858256071806,0.00764736300334
    % 
    % 
    %
```

When trying to read it:

```
import arff
arff.loads('result.arff')
```

I get the following error:

> arff.BadLayout: Invalid layout of the ARFF file, at line 1

I am not able to find the prblem. Weka opens the file but not with the python package... Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the ARFF module documentation at https://pythonhosted.org/liac-arff/, the load() takes a file object as input. It looks like you have the above data in result.arff file, so you should load it as:

```
fp = open('result.arff')
testdata = arff.load(fp)
```

This should resolve the above error related to the arff.BadLayout.

Answer (score 1):

[`loads` takes a string *containing the whole document*](https://pythonhosted.org/liac-arff/#arff.loads), not a filename:

> Convert a string instance containing the ARFF document into a Python object.

Either use `load` with a file object, or read the file into a string and pass it that way.